# What is Remote Method Invocation (RMI)?

Tags: java, rmi, distributed-system

I have found many explanations for RMI which appear to refer to different things. These are some conflicting points I have found.

- (Resolved) RMI is language independent **OR** RMI is for JAVA only (Thanks @EJP for the reference to RMI/JRMP and RMI/IIOP)
- RMI and RPC are both ways for distributed systems to communicate with each other **OR** RPC is a way for distributed systems to communicate with each other and RMI is only for JAVA objects to communcicate with each other.
- Remote Method Invocation is a broad term that describes how distributed systems communicate with each other **OR** RMI is a term that specifically describes how Remote Java Objects communicate with each other

Could someone give a definition of RMI in regards to these conflicting points?

Comment: You can get a bunch of information by simply clicking on the tag

Comment: Thanks for the tip but many of the answers I found conflict with each other which is why I have asked a new question.

Comment: Where exactly does it say RMI is language independent?

Comment: My lecturer mentioned it in slides, with your reference to RMI/IIOP, I understand that it meant RMI over IIOP, can be language independent.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation
From here, I clicked on Remote Method Invocation and got directed to here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_object_communication
They gave examples of CORBA/JAVA RMI/... I understand that wikipedia is not a reliable source though.

http://www.inf.unibz.it/~nutt/Teaching/DSs0910/DSsSlides/5-remMethodInvocation-2.pdf Slide 7, gave example of CORBA, which is Language Independent

Comment: http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/courses/02222/Spring_2011/W4L1/Chapter_05.pdf Slide 3
http://cs.gmu.edu/~setia/cs571-F02/slides/lec7a.pdf Slide 15 OR also Page 8/18 This has 2 slides in 1 Page

Comment: You're making this up. Not one of your cited slides says anything about RMI being language-independent. *IIOP* is language-independent. RMI/IIOP is Java-specific. All the other RMI's cited are language- or platform-specific. I've fixed a lot of things in Wikipedia. You certainly can't rely on it and you even more certainly cannot cite it, and they say so themselves in a Wikipedia entry entitled 'Wikipedia is not a reliable source'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is Remote Method Interface (RMI)?

It isn't. It is Remote Method *Invocation.*

> These are some conflicting points I have found.
>
> RMI is language independent OR RMI is for JAVA only

I'm not aware of any other things called RMI in other languages, and if they existed they could not communicate with Java RMI. I'm curious to know where you read otherwise.

> RMI and RPC do the same thing except RMI is object-oriented OR RMI is a way of implementing RPC (Are they the same "level" or is RMI an example of RPC?)

These statements are not in conflict, but RMI isn't really a way of *implementing* RPC, and again I'm curious where you read otherwise. RMI is remote *method* calls, on an *object*, where RPC is remote *procedure* calls, without objects.

> RMI is Remote Method Invocation in JAVA only OR Remote Method Invocation can be implemented with CORBA, .NET Remoting, JAVA RMI or other ways.
> Could someone give a definition of RMI in regards to these conflicting points?

RMI/JRMP and RMI/JERI are Java only. RMI/IIOP is also Java only, but it can interoperate with CORBA implementations in other languages, subject to various restrictions. .NET Remoting is a different thing altogether.

Re your **EDIT:**

> RMI and RPC are both ways for distributed systems to communicate with each other

Yes.

> OR RPC is a way for distributed systems to communicate with each other and RMI is only for JAVA objects to communcicate with each other.

No. RMI is object-oriented RPC. I had already stated that before you asked in your edit.

> Remote Method Invocation is a broad term that describes how distributed systems communicate with each other

*Can* communicate with each other.

> OR RMI is a term that specifically describes how Remote Java Objects communicate with each other.

No. RMI is a way for a client to call methods on a remote object, and that statement isn't inconsistent with what's before the 'or'. It is not about two remote objects communicating with each other, except as a special case.

I don't consider these new questions do anything except restate the original confusion.

Comment: Ah yes. RMI does mean Remote Method Interface. I have edited my question to reflect that.

Comment: Also, Thanks for answering this question but I realised that I may have phrased my points poorly. I will change my question description.

Comment: Ah  yes it *doesnt* mean Remote Method Interface. Again.

Comment: Oh! Gosh so embarassing, *Yes Invocation

Comment: Accepting your answer since it helped me. I've confirmed that Java RMI is different from Remote Invocation/Remote Method Invocation. Most text/answers don't make the distinction obvious when they say RMI though. Java RMI is specifically for Java's implementation for Remote Method Invocation. Remote Method Invocation is a general term for Distributed Systems and can be done in other languages like C++.
 
Source: https://azmuri.files.wordpress.com/2013/09/george-coulouris-distributed-systems-concepts-and-design-5th-edition.pdf

Comment: It isn't 'different'. It is a *specific implementation*.

Comment: And Remote Method Involcation isn't 'a general term for distributed systems'.